# How to close a dialog with an OK button using a condition

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qdialog

[image: My dialog window]

[My code](https://pastebin.com/wGT1u9Nc)

my first attempt so I could get the result in Mainwindow.cpp but it could be //incorrect

```
void Dialog::on_buttonBox_accepted()
 {
     Cities.clear();
     for(int row = 0; row<ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); row++)
     {
         cities s(get_city(row),get_time(row,3),get_time(row,4));
         Cities.push_back(s);
     }
 }
// my attempt to make another button but I could not get a result in 
//Mainwindow.cpp but could check correctly
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(cities_is_filled())
    {
        Cities.clear();
        for(int row = 0; row<ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); row++)
        {
            cities s(get_city(row),get_time(row,3),get_time(row,4));
            Cities.push_back(s);
        }
    }
}

//GET RESULT
void MainWindow::on_actionAdd_train_triggered()
{
    Dialog e;
    if(e.exec())
    {
       for(auto City: e.Cities)
       {
           ui->textBrowser->append(City.city_+ " " + City.depart_+ " " 
           +City.leave_);
       }
    }
}
```

If the table cell is empty when I press OK, the dialog closes - but I would like it to *not* close. How can I implement this?

Comment: You can either reimplement the [QDialog::accept()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) slot or not connecting the button box to it. If you share the code of your dialog, I could help you with an example of how to do it.

Comment: plz write your code...

Comment: my code https://pastebin.com/aQe7iRDe

Comment: it is mainwindow.cpp where i print results

Comment: void MainWindow::on_actionAdd_train_triggered()
{
    Dialog e;
    if(e.exec())
    {
       for(auto City: e.Cities)
       {
           ui->textBrowser->append(City.city_+ " " + City.depart_+ " " +City.leave_);
       }
    }
}

Comment: @markblacksmith. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47239664/edit) and show all the relevant code there. It's very hard to read code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press right click mouse on your `buttonBox` then select `Go To Slot...` then choose `accepted()` slot.

[image]

[image]

Now add your condition to the accepted function:

```
void MainWindow::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    if(ui->tableWidget->item(1,2)->text() != "") // for example
    {

    }
    else
    {
        qApp->exit();
    }
}
```

[QDialogButtonBox Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html)